# Sonarsource C# plugin is not showing Unit Test Sucess %

Tags: sonarqube, xunit.net, dotcover

Is anyone else facing this issue. ? When you run the msbuild scanner Unit Test Success percentage is not showing up. Using

Sonar source C# 5.3.2
SonarQube 5.6
Jenkins Msbuild Sonar scanner plugin
Xunit 2.0.0 console runner
Dotcover

```
/d:sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=
/d:sonar.dotnet.version=
/d:sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths="xunit-results.xml"
/d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths="reports/CoverageReport.html"
/d:sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies="UniTests/**/bin/Release/*.Tests.dll"
```

Also using Jenkins SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild

Comment: Which properties did you pass to the Scanner for MSBuild ? (edit your post with full command-line invoked) Any findings from the analysis logs ?

Comment: Still having issues as Unit test success % is not showing. Is there anything that i am missing above in properties?